# Button work on desktop, resized to mobile but dont react on real mobile

Tags: javascript, api, mobile

i'm learning Api my nearly first thing. There is a search button that stop working at mobile.
Can't find a reason/ could u have a look?

https://codepen.io/DeanWinchester88/pen/ExvxdxX

```
 function showPokemonSearchResult(){
    
   let enteredPokemonName = document.getElementById("pokemonNameByUser").value;
   targetPokemon = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${enteredPokemonName}`
    console.log("target pokemon",targetPokemon)
   
    fetch(targetPokemon)
       .then(res  =>  {
          if(res){
            console.log("Success");
            // console.log("res.json",res.json());
            return res.json()
            
            }else {
            console.log("Failure");
          }
         })
        .then(data  =>{
         
        let gotDivForPokemonSearchResult = document.getElementById("divForPokemonSearchResult");
        gotDivForPokemonSearchResult.innerHTML = `
        <h2>  ${data.name}</h2><br>
        <img src=${data.sprites["front_default"]}></img>
        <img src=${data.sprites["back_default"]}></img>
        <p class="text2">Weight: ${data.weight}</p>
        <p class="text2">Heigth: ${data.height}</p>
        <p class="text2">Base experience: ${data["base_experience"]}</p>
        `
        console.log(data.id)
          
    })
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "stop working"? Does it show an error? I see casing is considered, so if your mobile keyboard corrects venusaur with Venusaur the search will fail.

Comment: ah ye. first letter uppercase was the issue. u may right the answer

Comment: Great! I added an answer with a possible solution, using `.toLowerCase()`, if you want to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see, `pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/` is case sensitive and from mobile the keyboard usually puts the first letter uppercase.

For example, if your mobile keyboard corrects venusaur with Venusaur the search will fail.

You might consider adding a `.toLowerCase()` when you read the input to avoid this issue at all.

```js
let enteredPokemonName = document.getElementById("pokemonNameByUser").value.toLowerCase();
```